# SQL get, edit and update data

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, sql-update

I'm trying to get an int, add another int and write the new data in one sql command. How can I do this? Here is my solution approach but I does not work.

```
update accounts set credit = ((select credit from accounts where id = 1679407)+1) where id=1679407;
```

The error looks like this.

```
Error Code: 1093. Table 'accounts' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data  0.125 sec
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to want this:

```
update accounts
    set credit = credit + 1
    where id = 1679407;
```

Comment: Thank you! 
I thought too complicated :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that you are updating the same table from which you are retrieving the data at first. 
As per the quotation given in this [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)

> You cannot update a table and select from the same table in a
>   subquery.

Though there is a workaround for that as following

```
 Update accounts
      set credit = 
          ( (select a.credit from 
                         (select *from accounts)as a where id=1679407)+1) 
                                                                  where id=1679407;
```

Although it's quite complicated way to achieve much simpler task of yours as you just want to increment the credit by 1 and that only for a particular id.
Also the way shown above may cause performance issues sometimes.

Hence the easiest and the most efficient way to do your task is the way the  @Gordon Linoff gave in his answer.

```
update accounts
    set credit = credit + 1
    where id = 1679407;
```

Hope you've learned something from this answer apart from finding the solution of your problem.